# I need to remove seconds from a javascript file based on time

Tags: javascript

I have looked up how to remove seconds from javascript time fetch. I have checked the worldclock API website. I am not familiar with JS, so I dont know the right question to input into search. Here is my code, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to remove seconds from the received output.

I want to go from HH:MM:SS to just HH:MM. I would appreciate any help. Thank you

```
window.onload = (ev => {
   getTime().then();
});
let count = 0;

async function getTime(){
    count+=1;
    let data = await fetch('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/GMT+3'); 
    let res = await data.json();
    let result = res.datetime.toString();
    let time = result.substring(11,19)

    let digital_clock = document.getElementById('content')
    digital_clock.innerHTML = time;
    getTime().then();
    console.log(count);
```

Comment: Reduce the substring end limit to 16. You will get it in HH:MM

Comment: *(I didn't downvote you.)* This isn't a bad or stupid question. However, likely this type of information is easily found online (or SO users expect you to show some "effort" and describe the problem thoroughly). You don't need to delete the question, but do realize that the next time you ask.

Comment: I did search as much as I understand how to formulate the search. Everything I searched didnt work or fall inline with my code. I did try for a couple hours.

Comment: thank you!!! That makes so much sense. @Jyotirmay Dash

Comment: For your next search, you need to focus on the actual problem and remove the unrelated things. What you are trying to do is simply extract part of a string. You want to turn `2022-03-15T19:00:30.942933-03:00` into `19:00`. This is not really about a file, or seconds or APIs.

Comment: You ask a question, people tell you to google the answer, when you google it you find your question. Welcome to StackOverflow! Always make sure you know what to look for when explaining you don't know what to look for.

Comment: Don't worry, this question wasn't stupid. In case they did, my comments below suchislife's answer weren't supposed to make you feel embarrassed, they were addressed solely at suchislife, who shouldn't know better than to post an answer to a typo question.

Comment: Just to clarify: stackoverflow is about creating an exhaustive "last resort" FAQ of programming problems that aren't covered elsewhere. It does not work like a casual chat forum where people just randomly post stuff. Any question and any answer should be regarded as contributing to a gold standard FAQ, not a discord chat. Unfortunately, management no longer communicates this to newbies, and even some longtime members appear to post here for points, and not in light of the above.

Comment: @ChrisG yeah after reading all these comments, I realize that stackoverflow is meant for advanced and extremely specific questions. The website needs to clarify that better because I did go through their question tutorial and that was not addressed by them. I saw other posts like "how do I include a JS file in a JS file". I thought that was a simple question too. So, I posted because a self taught guy like me is oblivious in how to find the answer, and thought this site could help. At this point, I am unsuccessful in deleting this post. I think you guys can delete it because it doesn't belong.

Comment: Again, don't worry about it. Finding an existing answer can be really hard if you aren't used to narrowing down a problem to its core. I know because it literally took me years to learn how to do it.

Comment: Love it. First they destroy your self esteem as a new comer. Then try to cleverly explain why you shouldn't feel bad. Because you know, they explained why you shouldn't, so you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to uh... well, let's get to it.

**Change this line:**

`let time = result.substring(11,19)`

**...to this line:**

`let time = result.substring(11,16)`

What we're doing here is shortening the extracted string to include just hours and minutes.

Comment: Neither this question nor this answer is something that is supposed to be added to stackoverflow. And please do not send people to w3schools.

Comment: Jesus... Christ. Hey. Don't worry about it. Let's me remove it so we can together teach exactly nothing.

Comment: This is stackoverflow. How to use substring() is taught elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah. Earth. Not where ever you think you are.

Comment: How does the fact that I'm advising OP on how to do a relevant search imply that I expected them to know what to search for in advance? Also, you are a ten year member. Shouldn't you know how this website works?

Comment: It wont let me delete since so many commented, I dont think I will ever ask a question again. This is embarrassing.

Comment: I am a graphic designer just trying to create something specific to my art. Again, apologies for asking a stupid question.

Comment: @Merc okay, getting slightly out-of-hand. Just ask some more questions, be careful, and forget this ever happened. There's nothing wrong with the question, in my opinion. Just some people arguing about w3schools and SO.

Comment: "I dont think I will ever ask a question again." ~ How's that for inspiration, CG?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the datetime to Date Object and then you have access to some methods. Afterwards you can build your own date what you wish.

```js
fetch('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/GMT+3')
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => {
    const date = data.datetime
    const res = {
      year: new Date(date).getFullYear(),
      month: new Date(date).getMonth() + 1,
      day: new Date(date).getDate(),
      hours: new Date(date).getHours(),
      minutes: new Date(date).getMinutes()
    }
     console.log(res)
})
```